# Xpointer is a non valid IRI?

Tags: rdf, jena, xpointer, iri

I'm trying out a tool ([Elda](http://elda.googlecode.com)) that uses the Jena framework for handling RDF.

I got this error:

> ERROR [qtp1415899750-24] (RouterRestlet.java:332) - Exception: Line 7,
>   column 72: com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.impl.IRIImplException:
>   
>   Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in FRAGMENT: The character violates the
>   grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.

It says the following URL is not a valid IRI.

> http://burckhardt.netseven.it/show_annotable_transcription?id=12#xpointer(start-point(string-range(//DIV[@about='http://burckhardt.netseven.it/show_annotable_transcription?id=12']/DIV[1]/BLOCKQUOTE[1]/P[1]/text()[1],'',13))/range-to(string-range(//DIV[@about='http://burckhardt.netseven.it/show_annotable_transcription?id=12']/DIV[1]/BLOCKQUOTE[1]/P[1]/text()[1],'',27)))

I know it is ugly, but as far as I understand it conforms XPointer specification...
And I'm using it successfully in other environments (e.g. Sesame triplestore).

Does someone get what is wrong in it?

thank you

Christian

Answer (score 6):

According to [rfc2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt) the `[` and `]` should only be used for encoding IPv6 addresses

> 1. Changes to RFC 2396
>
>    This document updates the generic syntax for Uniform Resource
>      Identifiers defined in RFC 2396 [URL].  It defines a syntax for IPv6
>      addresses and allows the use of "[" and "]" within a URI explicitly
>      for this reserved purpose.

Since your url does not encode an IPv6 address within the `[]`s, this is deemed an illegal URL

Comment: Exaclty, and in [rfc3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) (the current URI spec) `[]` are reserved along with `: / ? # @`. RDF uses IRIs ([rfc3987](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt)), but the restriction remains.

Comment: Note that the XPointer framework recommendation [does discuss escaping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-framework/#escapingModel).